# Using Android NDK and C++

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

I got the sample HelloJni project working, which uses a C file for the native code.  I have not been able to get any simple examples working with C++.  Take the following JNI code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_testActivity_doSomething(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{

}
```

If I have the code in a .c file, it works fine.  If I change the extension to .cpp it compiles fine, but blows up when running (force closes).  Since the library and method signature is the same either way, I don't suspect the problem being on the Java side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might need to surround your code with an `extern "C"` block:

```
extern "C" {

    JNIEXPORT ...

}
```

You should be able to make a version that will work in both C and C++ by wrapping the extern block in `#if`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: why do we need to add extern c?

Answer (score 1):

Java_com_test_testActivity_doSomething will need to be extern "C".

Answer (score 1):

try putting extern "C" around the exported function definitions.