# Android NDK C++ Class undefined Reference

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

First.h

```
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

class Test
{
public:
void create();
void test();

private:


};



#endif /* FIRST_H */
```

Second.cpp

```
#include "first.h"


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

jint

Java_com_example_ndkcpp2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    Test t;
    t.test();

}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When I do a NDK-Build on second.cpp    I got

pp2/jni/second.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'Test::test()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Where are you defining `Test::test`? How are you specifying which files to link?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292190/using-android-ndk-and-c

Comment: I define it in the first.h file right? test should be a member function of the First Class.

Comment: @lilzz: You're *declaring* it there, in the class definition. There's no definition (that is, the implementation, with the code for the function body) in the code you've posted. Where is the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Using C++, you declare Class in .h file and write implementation in .cpp file. for example, you created First.h, then you should create First.cpp, in which write your method implementation like `void Test::test(){}`. Remember to add First.cpp to your makefile(Android.mk) for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here assuming that you have a first.cpp file that you implemented the Test class correctly. Without being able to see your Android.mk, I will go through all options:

Build First.cpp as a static or shared library and add this library to your module which compiles Second.cpp. Your Android.mk should look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := firstlib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/first.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

If you would like First to be a shared library instead of a static library, change include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) line to:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now, your second lib is compiled as follows:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := second
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/first.h
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += path/to/second.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := second.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := firstlib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If firstlib is built as shared library, you can link it by chaning LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += firstlib line to the following:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += firstlib
```

As a second solution, you can build first.cpp as a part of the second lib and this way you don't have to worry about linking against the first library. This is more like a design choice and how you would like to shape up your libraries:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-second
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-second
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/first.h
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += path/to/second.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += second.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Finally, you can find a sample of the first approach in your NDK directory, under samples/twolibs.